# What shell verb used in double click action?

Tags: .net, windows, registry, windows-shell, shell-verbs

I'm trying to programmatically open .jpg file in Windows Server 2008 R2.

```
var fileName = @"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\TEST.JPG";
Process.Start(fileName);
```

But this code causes an error, because Photo Gallery Viewer component is not installed in the system.

[image]

But if I open the file by double click from explorer, it opens in MS Paint. In the register there is only one verb "printto". How Windows open file in MS Paint? What verb used by default in double click action?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I dont have **Windows Server 2008 R2**, but afaik Windows Shell uses [Perceived Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/bb776871%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) mechanism. So If Shell dont know, how open JPEG file type, looks `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\image\OpenWithList` key and hooray - **mspaint.exe**.